# как узнать размеры imageview?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

я так понимаю есть какой то метод, чтобы узнать размеры imageview на экране. когда создается в onCreate, то размеры ещё не известны. куда копать? И ещё. после того как я нажимаю на кнопку, чтобы сменить изображение, появляются размеры imageview, но они не совпадают с размером изображения. то есть imageview например 1080, а изображение меньше на много пикселей, хотя фактический размер изображения больше 1080. он масштабируется и не понятно как с этим справиться.

Comment: размеры появятся в onWindowFocusChanged, размер ImageView и самого изображения - это 2 разные вещи

Comment: @Style-7, а как узнать размер изображения? так то я решил проблему с помощью picasso. но хотелось бы знать ответ на вопрос.

Comment: нужно достать BItmap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306623/get-bitmap-attached-to-imageview

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы узнать размер самого `Image`, вытягиваешь его из `ImageView` методом `getImage()`. Тебе вернёт объект картинки, потом уже из неё вытягиваешь размер методами `getWidth()` и `getHeight()`.